# Problems with serializable java

Tags: java, android, serialization

I am triying to implement serializable in java but i obtain an  excepcion.

This is my serializable class:

```
public class Serialize implements java.io.Serializable {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        public double dis1;
        public double dis2;
        public double error1;
        public double error2;
        public double coorx;
        public double coory;
        public double coorz;

    }
```

And this when i create object of this class and try to convert to bytes.

```
Serialize serial = new Serialize();
        serial.dis1 = dis1;
        serial.dis2 = dis2;
        serial.error1 = error1;
        serial.error2 = error2;
        serial.coorx = coorx;
        serial.coory = coory;
        serial.coorz = coorz;

        byte[] bytes = null;
        int length = 0;

        try {

            ByteArrayOutputStream bs = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            ObjectOutputStream os = new ObjectOutputStream(bs);
            os.writeObject(serial); ///EXCEPCION
            os.close();
            bytes = bs.toByteArray();
            length = bytes.length;

        } catch (IOException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

What am i doing wrong?

Logcat:

```
04-24 09:15:29.734: W/System.err(4279): java.io.NotSerializableException: org.gradiant.sistole.locservice.Communication
04-24 09:15:29.734: W/System.err(4279):     at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeNewObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1364)
04-24 09:15:29.734: W/System.err(4279):     at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObjectInternal(ObjectOutputStream.java:1671)
04-24 09:15:29.734: W/System.err(4279):     at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1517)
04-24 09:15:29.734: W/System.err(4279):     at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1481)
04-24 09:15:29.734: W/System.err(4279):     at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeFieldValues(ObjectOutputStream.java:979)
04-24 09:15:29.734: W/System.err(4279):     at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:368)
04-24 09:15:29.734: W/System.err(4279):     at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeHierarchy(ObjectOutputStream.java:1074)
04-24 09:15:29.734: W/System.err(4279):     at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeNewObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1404)
04-24 09:15:29.734: W/System.err(4279):     at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObjectInternal(ObjectOutputStream.java:1671)
04-24 09:15:29.734: W/System.err(4279):     at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1517)
04-24 09:15:29.734: W/System.err(4279):     at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1481)
04-24 09:15:29.734: W/System.err(4279):     at org.gradiant.sistole.locservice.Communication.datarequest(Communication.java:447)
04-24 09:15:29.734: W/System.err(4279):     at org.gradiant.sistole.locservice.UWBmain.process(UWBmain.java:311)
04-24 09:15:29.734: W/System.err(4279):     at org.gradiant.sistole.locservice.UWBmain$2.run(UWBmain.java:279)
04-24 09:15:29.734: W/System.err(4279):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

thanks

Comment: Your Object is called Serialize ? isn't it forbidden ? Anyway, the problem seems to be in your org.gradiant.sistole.locservice.Communication class

Comment: I change name of the class, but issue continues

Comment: Does your "Serialize" class contain any other object? I mean other than the double fields.

Comment: Just guessing... ¿is this by chance an inner class? If so, make it static!

Comment: Try to modify the value of your serialVersionUID : private static final long serialVersionUID = 87418L; // random long ...

Comment: change serialVersionUID not fix nothing

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you try to serialize an object of class org.gradiant.sistole.locservice.Communication, is this an object inside the class you try to serialize? if so than that object should also implement serializable to serialize the object. if you don't need the object you can make it transient like so:

```
 transient Communication comm = new Communication(...);
```

than this object will not be serialized and it will be null if you deserialize the object.

If you cannot implement serializable and you do need it at deserialization then you have to figure out a way to rebuild the object at deserialization.

Comment: umm i don´t understand very well.. Class wich i want to serialize (Serialize) is inside of Communication class. And when i try to serialize object is in public method of Communication class

Comment: Is Communication its supertype? The javadoc for writeObj() says: "Write the specified object to the ObjectOutputStream.  The class of the object, the signature of the class, and the values of the non-transient and non-static fields of the class and all of its supertypes are written."